# Плавающая кнопка в javascript

Tags: javascript

Я написал скрипт,который не дает перейти плавающей кнопке выше области, где используется скрипт, при прокрутке вниз кнопка лезет до самого низа сайта. Как сделать, чтобы она останавливалась в конце блока, где используется мой скрипт?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var offset = $(".spoiler-hd").offset();
    var topPadding = 45;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $(".spoiler-hd").stop().animate({marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding});
      }
      else {$(".spoiler-hd").stop().animate({marginTop: 300});};});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы начинаете двигать элемент в момент, когда позиция прокрутки документа больше позиции верхней грани нужного Вам блока (`$(window).scrollTop() > offset.top`).

Ничего Вам не мешает добавить туда условие не двигающее элемент, когда прокрутка прошла нижнюю грань нужного Вам блока. То есть, например:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top && 
        $(window).scrollTop() < (offset.top + offset.offsetHeight) )
```

Comment: Извините не совсем понял как это должно выглядеть..
Как мне правильно оформить ввесь скрипт,пока не работает

Comment: @user, я просто заменил Ваше условие в `if`'е. Вполне вероятно, что я, не видя Вашей разметки, ошибаюсь. )

Comment: @user, Вы разобрались? Могу написать более подробный ответ, если нет.

Comment: не разобрался(
Пожалуйста объясните